# cannot resolve method add(int , new tFragment()).commit() in android studion 1.0.1

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was working with fragments in android studio 1.0.1. Just as network process are not good to be done in the main UI, i moved my code to a different class containing fragments.
But what happened afterwards is not helping me proceed at all. the error i get is cannot resolve method `add(R.id.container, new com.sunshine.example.sunshine.app.Fragment).commit();`
down here is the code snippet of my MainActivity class but all is well with Fragment class.

```
package com.sunshine.example.sunshine.app;
      import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
      import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
      import android.os.Bundle;    
      import android.view.Menu; 
      import    android.view.MenuItem; 

      public class    MainActivity extends    ActionBarActivity {

      @Override    
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                  add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment()).commit();


      }    }

      @Override    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return true;    }
      @Override    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
      // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
      // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
      int id = item.getItemId();

      //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
      if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
          return true;
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    }
      }
```

Comment: show `ForecastFragment` class

Answer (score 25, accepted):

the compile time error is suggesting that your `ForecastFragment` is using the native fragment support `app.Fragment`, but in your activity you are using a transaction from the support library. You have to be consistent with the import. Change your `ForecastFragment` in order to make it use the Fragment from the support library

Comment: the Clearest answer i suppose !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're doing but it looks like you have a syntax error.

```
new com.sunshine.example.sunshine.app.Fragment*()*
```

You should put parentheses `()` at the end of any creating objects statement.

Comment: I'm sorry i missed the bracket at Fragment. It's add(int, new Fragment()).Commit()