# getChildFragmentManager - cannot resolve method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use a project for my app "YouTubePlaylist" https://github.com/akoscz/YouTubePlaylist.

I have make a `navigation drawer` and i want put this activity in fragment. So, i have try to create a `fragment` and put it in, but i have an error : `Cannot resolve method 'add(int, com.xx.xx.YouTubeReclyclerViewFragment)'`

This is my fragment :

```
public class YouTubeActivity extends Fragment {
    private static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    private YouTube mYoutubeDataApi;
    public static final String TAG = "YouTubeActivity";
    private final GsonFactory mJsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
    private final HttpTransport mTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    public static FragmentManager fgmanger;


    public void onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_activity, container, false);

        //setContentView(R.layout.);

            mYoutubeDataApi = new YouTube.Builder(mTransport, mJsonFactory, null)
                    .setApplicationName(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .build();


            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment.newInstance(mYoutubeDataApi, YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST))
                    .commit();

    }



}
```

How i can do resolve this error ? 
Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a conflict of libraries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849554/cannot-resolve-method-addint-new-tfragment-commit-in-android-studion-1-0

Comment: `public void onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` - This method doesn't exist in any `Activity` or `Fragment` classes by the way...you probably want `onCreateView()`.You're also calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in a place where it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library uses probably not the same `Fragment` class as you.

According to the Github project the [`YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment`](https://github.com/akoscz/YouTubePlaylist/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/akoscz/youtube/YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment.java) is a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, i.e. a subclass of the v4-support library's Fragment. And you are most likely using the native `android.app.Fragment`. These both Fragment classes are incompatible, thus the method `add()` cannot accept a Fragment of the other type.

That means you have to use the support library and use its Fragment class instead. Note that then you also have to use `AppCompatActivity` instead of the native Activity class.

To migrate from native classes to the support library, you may have a look at [this migration guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Migrating-to-the-AppCompat-Library).

Answer (score 0):

1).Try overriding `onCreateView()` for inflating layout in your YouTubeActivity  Fragment Class. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) for more clarity.

2). Try looking for imports for Fragment class in your YouTubeActivity and YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment.It should be consistent for both. Either you should import `android.app.Fragment` for both of these or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

3). I don't know why do you need `getChildFragmentManager()`(until unless it is a nested fragment case) for making FragmentTransaction in your case. The fragment transaction can be done by `getFragmentManager()` if you gonna use android.app.Fragment and with `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you will import your current YouTubeActivity Fragment with support fragment.