# How to go from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I cannot seem to find the answer to my problem.

I have tried the solution of this post: 
[How to go to fragment from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011374/how-to-go-to-fragment-from-activity) as shown below:

> You need to created a class that extends FragmentActivity and start
>   yourfragment there

```
public class MessagesFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, new MessagesFragment ()).commit();}
    }
}
```

> Your fragment constructor.

```
public YourFragment() {
}
```

> then from you calling activity, start your fragment activity in the
>   normal way

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this,MessagesFragment.class);
startActivity(i);
```

But it does not work for me as my activity extends AppCompatActivity, so I cannot extend FragmentActivity.

In this case, I tried creating a new activity which extends FragmentActivity and link an intent to this new activity instead, then this new activity would then move to the fragment.

**Below are my codes:**

In my Activity:

```
saveBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listName.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    listName.requestFocus();
                    listName.setError("Required field");
                } else {
                    if (listOwner.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        listOwner.requestFocus();
                        listOwner.setError("Required field");
                    } else {
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", userid));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", listName
                                .getText().toString()));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OwnerName",
                                listOwner.getText().toString()));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CompanyName",
                                companyName.getText().toString()));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CompanyAddress",
                                companyAddress.getText().toString()));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CompanyPhone",
                                companyNumber.getText().toString()));

                        for (int d = 0; d < CustomFieldsList.size(); d++) {
                            CustomFields field = CustomFieldsList.get(d);
                            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(field
                                    .getFieldID());
                            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                                checkboxChecked.add(Integer.toString(field
                                        .getFieldID()));
                            }
                        }

                        new SaveContact().execute();
                        Intent back = new Intent(AddContactListActivityOCR.this, Revert.class);
                        startActivity(back);
                        finish();
                    }
```

In my New Activity (Revert.java):

```
public class Revert extends FragmentActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, new FragmentContactLists()).commit();}
    }

}
```

However, it shows the following error in here:
[image]

What went wrong?

**-------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------**

After trying @saeed answer:

It leads to the following:
[image]
[image]

Although I imported "android.support.v4.app.Fragment;", it still shows this error.

Comment: check it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849554/cannot-resolve-method-addint-new-tfragment-commit-in-android-studion-1-0) helps

Comment: What is `FragmentContactLists ` . show your code

Comment: Does your FragmentContactList extend Fragment (or one of it's children)?

Comment: And what is your xml layout for the main activity from where you control your fragments, do you have a container for them?

Comment: I guess you have a fragment, and you need to close the fragment and show Activity?

Comment: open your FragmentContactList and import android.app.Fragment change to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; , your use getSupportFragmentManager him need fragment with support, or getSupport change to getFragmentManager

Comment: you please post complete code MessagesFragmentActivity  .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
On your Fragment:

```
 public static MyFragment createFragment() {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        return fragment;
    }
```

On your activity:

```
mFragment = MyFragment.createFragment();

       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(
            R.id.fragment_container,
            mFragment).commit();
```

Comment: It says "Non-static field 'MyFragment' cannot be referenced from a static content"

Comment: instead mFragment= MyFragment.createFragment()
try MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

Its the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This works for me.

and make sure that you have import V4 fragment.
Use replace instead of add.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_content_id, new SubscriptionFragment(), "")
                      .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have  a framelayout in your activity xml where you want to use the fragment, id that framelayout to @+id/content  ..and replace "android.R.id.content" in your code to R.id.content.
That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You Please replace this code

```
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
  .add(android.R.id.content, new new FragmentContactLists()).commit();
```

to

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.id.container, new new FragmentContactLists()).commit();
```

and you replace  actyity layout like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">

</FrameLayout>
```

In your FragmentContactList you  import android.app.Fragment. change it to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution by creating a new xml for Revert.java and pasted your activity layout codes. Now it shows this error, please check my edit, thanks :)

Comment: In your Fragment class import  android.support.v4.app.Fragment;  currentl;y you  may import  import  android.app.Fragment;

Comment: I tried but it still shows the same error, thanks :)

Comment: can you check your FragmentContactList class ... You import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment mRideHistory = new fragmentAny();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mRideHistory)
                .addToBackStack(getPackageName()).commit();
```

This is a right format for activity to fragment.
Use getActivity in any place you need to add this.
i hope this information will help you.